# Nested for Loops in Python - Cipher

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I need assistance with nested for loops related to a cipher (caesar cipher - brute force). When I add a range it keeps adding onto an inputted string. For example:

string input = abc

What I'm getting:

1. bcd
2. bcdcde
3. bcdcdedef

What is should be:

1. bcd
2. cde
3. def

I know I need to add another variable, but just don't know how.

Thanks

Code:

```
for o in range(1,4):
        for char3 in str3:
             force += chr(ord(char3) - o)
        print(o, force)
```

Comment: make sure to set force to an empty string again in your loop

Comment: cool, thanks....I thought it was something simple.